# Adding a script to two pages in my site

Tags: php, wordpress

Im trying to get my Google Maps js loaded on two pages. One is a page template and the other is a single post type page.

template-homepage.php
single-destinations.php

I have a enqueue scripts file to load all my scripts in the header and footer. Here is the code im trying to use but its not loading the scripts at all.

```
if (is_singular('destinations') && is_page_template('template-homepage.php')) :
    wp_enqueue_script( 'google-maps-js', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyebtdsdfgdAmyvSWk8wXmvdmtD83PR4vrCZuYs&libraries=places' );
endif;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dan,

How can it be destinations AND template-homepage at the same time?

Try changing this:

`if (is_singular('destinations') && is_page_template('template-homepage.php')) :`

To:

`if (is_singular('destinations') || is_page_template('template-homepage.php')) :`

Comment: ahhh, yes you are very right. I was thinking about my logic a little wrong. Thanks for the help.